# After deleting last record get api not getting called.refresh not happening

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have set of accordians after deleting each accordian i call get api . problem is when i delete the last record from helpSupportList[] array the get Api is not called and the record is still displayed in view , after i reload page manually then the record is disappeared from UI ,please help me to call get api and auto refresh after deleting the last record

```
deleteHelpListRecord(contentId: number, content: any) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    let decision = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the record?");
    if (decision) {
      console.log("cane to the inside")
      let payload = {
        contentDesc: content.contentDesc,
        contentId: contentId,
        contentTopic: content.contentTopic,
        statusFlag: "N",
        fileNames: []
      }
      this.helpPageDataVO = payload;
      formData.append("helpPageDataVO", JSON.stringify(this.helpPageDataVO));
      for (let i = 0; i < this.myFiles.length; i++) {
        formData.append("files", this.myFiles[i]);
      }
      this.adminService.deleteHelpSupportList(formData).subscribe((res: any) => {
        if (res) {
          this.getHelpList();
          console.log(this.helpSupportList);
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

After deleting the last record please help me to autocall the get api and make the deleted las record disappear

Answer (score 0):

Assuming getHelpList() retrieves the latest list info and will then update the view.

Your problem is that your view is not being updated, only after a refresh.
Refresh is probably forcing getHelpList() to be called elsewhere.

I can guess either:

- .subscribe((res: any) is not being triggered/called
- .subscribe((res: any) is called with null/undefined/false so gets prevented by if statement

In order to give a more accurate answer I need to see more code (e.g. adminService)